# get account distinguish name AD on c++

Tags: c++, winapi, active-directory, distinguishedname

I would like to get  distinguish name "CN=XXX,CN=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com"
I know there is a function "LookupAccountSid" that get only the name of the account for SID.

Is there any similar function that get the distinguish name? 
on c++

Answer (score 0):

If you want user account name associated with the caller thread, use `GetUserNameEx` function with the `NameFullyQualifiedDN` parameter. You could obtain additional information using `IADsADSystemInfo` interface. 
If you want to enumerate domain accounts, you could use [ADSI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772212(v=vs.85).aspx) interfaces.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay.
I have look on IADsGroup interface and there is a method called "IsMember" that check if a user is an immediate member of the group.
Is there any to know if a user is member of nested group? 
using ADSI interfaces.

Comment: ADSI does not have such a method. Some approaches to solve this problem were described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963771/adsi-indirect-group-membership